# I need to find the Translation Management Server version

Tags: translation-manager

In the process of trying to solve a translation problem for a client, I need to find the version of TMS the client is using. Can anyone help me find the version of TMS my client is running?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Translation Manager (TM) is installed as part of the core CMS (it's an optional checkbox in the install); if there are updates to something specific to TM then it would come under the guise of a CMS Hotfix (categorised to TM I'm sure).

The important thing to note is the TM in the *specific version of the CMS* will only support specific versions of SDL WorldServer, SDL Translation Management System (TMS) or SDL Language Cloud (Machine Translation)

See the page here for the CMS (TM) version to WS/TMS/MT support:
https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-AF1B8712-229D-496E-A8F8-C276ECE770AE